Infeasibility of subproblem in Combinatorial Benders Decomposition
I am working on a problem that is suitable to be applied with the Combinatorial Benders decomposition.
I read the Fischetti and Codato paper about the topic in order to implement it.
Probably I did not understand the theory because I am not able to make it work. So now I recap the theory and then I present my issue.
We start with the following problem:
$$
  \begin{array}{l@{\quad} r c r c}
    \min          & c^Tx &      &    \\
    \mathrm{s.t.} &   Fx & \leq & g \\
                  &   Mx & + & Ay & \geq &  b \\
                  &   Dy   & \geq &  e \\
                  &   x_j \in \{0,1\}
  \end{array}
$$
where $x$ and $y$ are vectors respectively of integer and continuous variables.  $M$ is a matrix with exactly one non zero element for every row $i$, corresponding to a variable $x_j$ that we denote the $x_j(i)$.
Here, we have the classical encoding with big M to say this constraint is active or not.
I have a practical problem that fits exactly this shape. The idea now is to use Benders and divide in the master problem with only $x$ variables and a subproblem where there are only $y$ variables because the $x$ ones are fixed as follows:
MASTER
$$
  \begin{array}{ r c r c r}
    \min          & c^Tx &      &    \\
    \mathrm{s.t.} &   Fx & \leq & g  \\
                  &   x_j \in \{0,1\}
  \end{array}
$$
SUBPROBLEM
$$
  \begin{array}{l@{\quad} r c r c r}
     &   Ay & \geq &  b-M\bar{x} \\
                  &   Dy   & \geq &  e
  \end{array}
$$
In the SUBPROBLEM program, $\bar{x}$ indicated the vector with fixed values of $x$. In this case, the SUBPROBLEM is only a satisfiability problem without an objective function.
Now what happens is that often the $\bar{x}$ are infeasible for the subproblem so we have to figure out a cut.
The authors proposed the following cut:
$$
   \sum_{i \in C, x_j(i) = 0} x_j + \sum_{i \in C, x_j(i) = 1} (1-x_j) \ge 1
$$
Where $C$ are the row of $A$ in the Minimal Infeasible Subsystem (MIS). The idea is to find this minimal subsystem and impose the cut that is simply saying one of these variables should change from 0 to 1 or from 1 to 0.
They proposed a way to compute this MIS and I am getting mad.
Their idea is to consider a general system similar to the subproblem and the corresponding dual:
PRIMAL
$$
  \begin{array}{l@{\quad} r c r c r}
    \min & 0^Ty \\
    \quad \mathrm{s.t.} &   \bar{A}y & \geq \bar{b} \\
  \end{array}
$$
Here the notation in the paper is not super clear to me.
I think that for $\bar{A}$ they consider the matrix composed by $A$ and $D$ in the subproblem $\bar{A} = [A;D]$ and the same for $\bar{b}=[b-M\bar{x};e]$.
Now they consider the dual.
DUAL
$$
  \begin{array}{l@{\quad} r c r c r}
    \max & u^T\bar{b} \\
    \quad \mathrm{s.t.} &   u^T\bar{A} & = &  0^T \\
                  &   u \geq 0
  \end{array}
$$
At this point the primal infeasibility can correspond to either dual infeasibility or dual unboundedness. They exclude the dual infeasibility since 0 is always a feasible solution.
For this reason they consider the unboundedness removing the objective function and adding the constraint $u^T\bar{b} = 1$. At this point the support of $u^*$ i.e. the component with $u$ greater than 0, correspond to minimal infeasible subsystem.
The problem is that when I add the constraint $u^T\bar{b} = 1$ the dual is infeasible and I am not able to compute the MIS.
I checked all the problems both dual and primal by hand and the formulations are right, so I decided to ask because maybe I did not understand the theory.
EDIT: I present a small example to show why I am in trouble.
Let us consider the following toy primal model:
PRIMAL
$$
  \begin{array}{l@{\quad} r c r c r}
    \min & 0^Ty \\
    \quad \mathrm{s.t.} &   y_3-y_5 & \geq 4-m*(1-\bar{x}_1) \\
                        &   y_4-y_5 & \geq 4-m*(1-\bar{x}_2) \\
                        &   y_3-y_5 & \geq 1-m*(1-\bar{x}_2) \\
                        &   y_4-y_5 & \geq 1-m*(1-\bar{x}_1) \\
                        &  -y_3 & \geq -3 \\
                        &   -y_4 & \geq -3 \\
                        &   -y_3+y_6 & \geq 0 \\
                        &   -y_4+y_6 & \geq 0 \\
                        &   -y_1+y_3 & \geq 0 \\
                        &   -y_2+y_4 & \geq 0 \\
                        &   y_j & \geq 0 \\
  \end{array}
$$
Here, $m$ is the big M equal to 20. We consider $\bar{x_1}=0$ and $\bar{x_2} = 1$. We get $\bar{b}= [-16;4;1;-19;-3;-3;0;0;0;0]$. The problem is infeasible. If you look at the second constraint, $y_4$ can be at maximum $3$, while $-y_5$ is for sure negative, so the expression can not be $\ge 4$.
Now we consider the dual where we substitute the objective function with the constraint $u^T\bar{b} = 1$.
DUAL
$$
  \begin{array}{l@{\quad} r c r c r}
    \max & 0^T \\
    \quad \mathrm{s.t.} &   -u_9 & = 0 \\
                        &   -u_{10} & = 0 \\
                        &   u_1+u_3-u_5-u_7+u_9 & = 0 \\
                        &   u_2+u_4-u_6-u_8+u_{10} & = 0\\
                        &  -u_1 -u_2 -u_3 -u_4 & = 0 \\
                        &   u_7 + u_8 & = 0 \\
                        &   -16u_1+4u_2 +1u_3-19u_4-3u_5-3u_6 & = 1 \\
                        &   u_k & \ge 0 \\
  \end{array}
$$
The dual is infeasible because constraint 5 imposes $u_1,u_2,u_3,u_4 = 0$. Simplifying the last constraint, we have $-3u_5 -3u_6 = 3$, which is infeasible.
If there are no errors in the derivation, I am in trouble with this situation.

If imposing $u^T \bar{b}=1$ makes the dual problem infeasible, it means that $u=0$ is the only feasible solution to the original dual and there is no certificate of infeasibility for the primal.  That is, the primal is feasible for that $\bar{x}$, and you should not be trying to add a feasibility cut to the master.

Thanks for the answer. I edited the initial question to show you what happens in my situation. If you have time, take a look.

The issue in your toy example is that you have $y \ge 0$ in the primal but then have equality (instead of $\le$) constraints in the dual.  Instead, $y$ should be free, in which case $x=(0,1)$ is feasible.

Alternatively, if you want $y \ge 0$, then the first fix dual constraints are $\le 0$, and the dual solution $u=(0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0)$ is optimal, yielding the desired MIS.

In my comment, “first fix” should have been “first six” instead.

Yeah, I got it. In the paper, they presented examples with positive $y$ so I thought the formulation considered these, but of course, the dual is always the dual. My bad. I take advantage for another last question. In the paper, after adding the equality constraint they suggest modeling the objective function using $\sum_i w_iu_i$ to drive the optimization in finding different MIS. At this point also if it is a dual max I can do whatever I want I think. Because my choice is $min \quad u_1+u_2+u_3+u_4$ so that I can minimize the support of dual variables linked to the big $m$ constraints.

Yes, you can use any dual objective, and $\min \sum_{i=1}^4 u_i$ yields $u_2=u_6=1$ as optimal.
